# Changing IPOPT options with pyomo doesn't work

Tags: pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

I am using IPOPT solver for solving KKTs conditions (a bunch of equality constraints and complementarity conditions).
For assigning the solver for the complementarity problem, I use the command line below:

`solver = po.SolverFactory('mpec_nlp')`

And then according to IPOPT [documentation](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html) I am changing the number of maximum iteration

`solver.options['max_iter']=1000`

But solver doesn't listen to me and still stops at its default maximum of 3000 iterations

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: I guess that max_iter will be send to the MPEC_NLP metasolver, which may just disregard the option. I don't know if there is a way to pass options to the solver that is called by MPEC_NLP.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating `ipopt.opt` file using notepad. Write `max_iter 500` into the file. Place the file into your working directory (where your code is running)

Comment: It didn't work out ;(

Comment: @errenmike1806 where have you tried to place ipopt.opt?

Comment: @furiois_bilbo at the same directory where my .py file is.

Comment: @errenmike1806 and where is your solver executable (ipopt.exe)?

Comment: @ furious_bilbo It is in the Anaconda3/Library/Bin. Now I moved ipopt.opt to Anaconda3/Library/Bin and it didn't work also :(

Comment: @errenmike1806 could you please send me an email with your `ipopt.opt` file? My email is alisher592@ya.ru